# Unable to convert pandas dataframe to csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to create a `dataset.csv` file from the various raw files within my `input_path`. However, my code didn't seem to generate the csv file.

```
    import os
    import pandas as pd
    from zipfile import ZipFile
    import cv2
    import re
    import csv
    from sklearn.dummy import DummyClassifier
    
    input_path = "../input_data/"
    
    
class RawToCSV:

    def __init__(self, path_, df):
        self.df = df
        self.measurement_df = None
        self.cls = None
        self.path_ = path_

    def raw_file_processing(self, path_):

        # Open all the subfolders within path
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_):
            for file in files:
                with open(os.path.join(root, file), "r") as data:
                    df = pd.read_csv(data)

                    # Create the ID series by concatenating columns 1-3
                    df = df.assign(ID=df[['cell_id:cell_id', 'region:region', 'tile_num:tile_num']].apply(
                        lambda row: '_'.join([str(each) for each in row]), axis=1))
                    df = df.drop(columns=['cell_id:cell_id', 'region:region', 'tile_num:tile_num'])

                    # The class info is the tile_num (i.e, column 3) - TODO: Check if class info is tile_num
                    cls_col = df.iloc[2]

                    # Dummy-code the classes
                    cls = pd.get_dummies(cls_col)

                    # Obtain measurement info
                    # Normalize data against blank/empty columns
                    # log-transform the data 
                    for col in df[9:]:
                        if re.search(r"(Blank|Empty)$", col):
                            background = col
                        else:
                            line = col.readline()
                            for data in line:
                                norm_data = data/ background
                                self.measurement_df = np.log2(norm_data)

        return self.df["ID"], cls, self.measurement_df

    def dataset_csv(self):
        """Col 1: ID
        Col 2: class
        Col 3-n: measurements"""
        ids = self.df["ID"]
        id_col = ids.to_frame()

        cls_col = self.cls.to_frame()
        frames = [id_col, cls_col, self.measurement_df]
        dataset_df = pd.concat(frames)
        data_csv = dataset_df.to_csv(r"../input_data/dataset.csv")

        return data_csv

dataset = RawToCSV.dataset_csv(input_path)
```

**Desired output `dataset.csv`**

| ID | Class | measurement_A | measurement_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sample1 | value | value | value |
| Sample2 | value | value | value |

Comment: Do you receive an error message ?

Comment: You are calling raw_file_processing function where as you are writing file in dataset_csv function. (Moreover, dataset_csv is not being called inside raw_file_processing function)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need to treat your url path as a row string. You should simply try:

```
data_csv = dataset_df.to_csv("../input_data/dataset.csv")
```

Ps : and as a test, start by saving your `csv` in the same folder where your script is:

```
data_csv = dataset_df.to_csv("dataset.csv")
```

Comment: Neither option generate the csv file. There's no error code.

Comment: By the way, are you sure that you're running your function `dataset_csv` somewhere ?

Comment: If neither is working, I would try adding the 'data_csv = dataset_df.to_csv("dataset.csv")' to the outside of the function. As it looks like the function creates/returns the csv, after this is complete then it should reach the to_csv line.

Comment: I think its because I didn't run `dataset_csv`.
But when I tried to call it using `dataset = RawToCSV.dataset_csv(input_path)`, I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'df'` error.